# How should secret files be pushed to an EC2 Ruby on Rails application using amazon web services with their elastic beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How should secret files be pushed to an EC2 Ruby on Rails application using amazon web services with their elastic beanstalk?

I add the files to a git repository, and I push to github, but I want to keep my secret files out of the git repository. I'm deploying to aws using:

```
git aws.push
```

The following files are in the .gitignore:

```
/config/database.yml
/config/initializers/omniauth.rb
/config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

Following this link I attempted to add an S3 file to my deployment:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

*Quoting from that link:*

> ### Example Snippet
>
> The following example downloads a zip file from an Amazon S3 bucket and unpacks it into /etc/myapp:
>
> ```
> sources:  
>     /etc/myapp: http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myobject
> ```

Following those directions I uploaded a file to an S3 bucket and added the following to a private.config file in the .ebextensions directory:

```
sources:
  /var/app/current/: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/config.tar.gz
```

That config.tar.gz file will extract to:

```
/config/database.yml
/config/initializers/omniauth.rb
/config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

However, when the application is deployed the config.tar.gz file on the S3 host is never copied or extracted.  I still receive errors that the database.yml couldn't be located and the EC2 log has no record of the config file, here is the error message:

```
Error message:
  No such file or directory - /var/app/current/config/database.yml
Exception class:
  Errno::ENOENT
Application root:
  /var/app/current
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and easy) to store sensitive files in S3 and copy them to your Beanstalk instances automatically.

When you create a Beanstalk application, an S3 bucket is automatically created. This bucket is used to store app versions, logs, metadata, etc.

The default `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` that is assigned to your Beanstalk environment has read access to this bucket.

So all you need to do is put your sensitive files in that bucket (either at the root of the bucket or in any directory structure you desire), and create a `.ebextension` config file to copy them over to your EC2 instances.

Here is an example:

```
# .ebextensions/sensitive_files.config

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXX"] # Replace with your bucket name
          roleName: 
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting": 
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" # This is the default role created for you when creating a new Beanstalk environment. Change it if you are using a custom role

files:
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key: # This is where the file will be copied on the EC2 instances
    mode: "000400" # Apply restrictive permissions to the file
    owner: root # Or nodejs, or whatever suits your needs
    group: root # Or nodejs, or whatever suits your needs
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXX/server.key # URL to the file in S3
```

This is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html

Answer (score 2):

The "right" way to do what I think that you want to do is to use IAM Roles. You can see a blog post about it here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/aws-iam/

Basically, it allows you to launch an EC2 instance without putting any personal credential on any configuration file at all. When you launch the instance it will be assigned the given role (a set of permissions to use AWS resources), and a rotating credential will be put on the machine automatically with Amazon IAM.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the `.ebextension/*.config` files be able to download the files from S3, they would have to be public. Given that they contain sensitive information, this is a Bad Idea.

You can launch an Elastic Beanstalk instance [with an instance role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html), and you can give that role permission to access the files in question. Unfortunately, the `file:` and `sources:` sections of the `.ebextension/*.config` files do not have direct access to use this role.

You should be able to write a simple script using the [AWS::S3::S3Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html) class of the [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) to download the files, and use a `command:` instead of a `sources:`. If you don't specify credentials, the SDK will automatically try to use the role.

You would have to add a policy to your role which allows you to download the files you are interested in specifically. It would look like this:

```
{                       
  "Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": "s3:GetObject",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you could do something like this in your `.config` file

```
files:
  /usr/local/bin/downloadScript.rb: http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/downloadScript.rb
commands:
  01-download-config:
    command: ruby /usr/local/downloadScript.rb http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/config.tar.gz /tmp
  02-unzip-config:
    command: tar xvf /tmp/config.tar.gz
    cwd: /var/app/current
```

Answer (score 1):

Using environment variables is a good approach. Reference passwords in the environment, so in a yaml file:

```
password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Then set them on the instance directly with eb or the console.

You may be worried about having such sensitive information readily available in the environment. If a process compromises your system, it can probably obtain the password no matter where it is. This approach is used by many PaaS providers such as Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

From there security document Amazon EC2 supports TrueCrypt for File Encryption and SSL for data in transit. Check out these documents

- [Security Whitepaper](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/pdf/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)
- [Features](http://aws.amazon.com/security/#features)
- [Risk and Compliance](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Risk_and_Compliance_Whitepaper.pdf)
- [Best Practices](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/Whitepaper_Security_Best_Practices_2010.pdf)

You can upload a server instance with an encrypted disk, or you can use a private repo (I think this costs for github but there are alternatives)

Comment: Well I think one of the biggest things here is ensuring that the correct permissions exist and that the app that is requesting the files from S3 have the correct permissions, but both are running under my user and I have permission to the files, so I'm not sure how to tell if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is not to hack AWS (set hooks, upload files). Just use ENV variables.

Use gem 'dot-env' for development (i.e. <%= ENV['LOCAL_DB_USERNAME'] %> in 'config/database.yml') and default AWS console to set variables in Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I couldn't find another answer anywhere so I burned the midnight oil to come up one.  I hope it saves you several hours.

I agreed with the devs that posted how much of a PITA it is to force devs to put ENV vars in their local dev database.yml.  I know the dotenv gem is nice but you still have to maintain the ENV vars, which adds to the time it takes to bring up a station.

My approach is to store a database.yml file on S3 in the bucket created by EB and then use a .ebextensions config file to create a script in the server's pre hook directory so it would be executed after the unzip to the staging directory but before the asset compilation--which, of course, blows up without a database.yml.

The .config file is

```
# .ebextensions/sensitive_files.config
# Create a prehook command to copy database.yml from S3
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_copy_database.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        set -xe
        EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config  container -k app_staging_dir)
        echo EB_APP_STAGING_DIR is  ${EB_APP_STAGING_DIR} >/tmp/copy.log
        ls -l ${EB_APP_STAGING_DIR} >>/tmp/copy.log
        aws s3 cp s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXX/database.yml ${EB_APP_STAGING_DIR}/config/database.yml >>/tmp/copy.log 2>>/tmp/copy.log
```

### *Notes*

- Of course the XXX in the bucket name is a sequence number created by EB.  You'll have to check S3 to see the name of your bucket.
- The name of the script file I create is important.  These scripts are executed in alphabetical order so I was careful to name it so it sorts before the asset_compilation script.
- Obviously redirecting output to /tmp/copy.log is optional

The post that helped me the most was at [Customizing ElasticBeanstalk deployment hooks](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137136)

posted by Kenta@AWS.  Thanks Kenta!